# URI tag of http.client.requests metric as NONE in Spring Boot 3.0.X

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

After migrate from spring boot 2.7.5 to spring boot 3.0.1.

The tag URI on the metric http.client.requests have the value none in all cases.

We build the URI of the restTemplate like

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(restTemplate.getUriTemplateHandler().expand("/hello"))
   .build()
   .toUri();

return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
```

I'm used to do it this way since to add query params, I think it's more easy to read and to manage.

To reproduce it I created two small application in [this repository](https://github.com/zizare/spring-boot-example-missing-uri-metrics) one on spring boot 2.7.7 and an other one on 3.0.1

I figure out it's linked to the new Observability on spring 6 and linked to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32484) on spring boot.

And Spring boot 2 customise the [UriTemplateHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3acd9b80e817f8591d8e191b6025f07e815e661c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/client/MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java#L120) and store the urlTemplate in ThreadLocal<Deque>. And use this deque for the tag uri.

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.spring-mvc) I know I could enhance the tag by providing a *new @Bean ClientRequestObservationConvention*.

I could also use *org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate#getForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>)*. like

```
return restTemplate.getForObject("/hello", String.class);
```

But I wonder if there is a way to get the previous behaviour and still used *org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate#getForEntity(java.net.URI, java.lang.Class)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Spring Boot 3 and the Observability improvements, `RestTemplate` would indeed [use the full request URI](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3bcc7ece55f88f3de6e59253205bfb5342d45a67/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/client/RestTemplateExchangeTags.java#L68) for the "uri" tag. This is wrong, as URI values are not bounded in an application and can cause cardinality explosion in the metrics system.

For example, a client could report uri tags with `"/user/12"`, `"/user/23"` etc. The correct tag for this should be low cardinality and use a request pattern like `"/user/{userId}"`.

In Spring Boot 2.x, for compatibility reasons, we did not alter this behavior but added instead a `MeterFilter` that stops recording metrics once a threshold is reached. As of Spring Framework 6, the instrumentation is built in `RestTemplate` directly. This tag is only recorded if a `RestTemplate` method accepting a String template, like `restTemplate.getForObject("/hello", String.class)` as you've noticed.

You can revert to the previous behavior by providing your own `ClientRequestObservationConvention` (see [the migration wiki for more on that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#deprecation-of-the-spring-boot-2x-instrumentation)) but note that you'll also need to ensure that cardinality explosion doesn't become an issue in your application.

See [this Spring Boot issue that looks quite similar](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22832).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.


I tried to enhance my question to show what behaviour changed.
Mostly I want to show if you build the uri based on "restTemplate.getUriTemplateHandler". The tag URI was working properly thanks to the MetricsRestTemplateCustomizer.


But I suppose using a ThreadLocal variable is not something that spring-boot wanted to keep for this usage. Or it might be subject for spring framework to enhance the RestTemplate.